# Script Manager 4.5 handling errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

I have a script manager (ASP.NET 4.5 - MSForms.js etc) i am working on methods to handle errors.

And i have mapped the following (which worked properly previous versions)

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandler);
```

This works great in the event of a failure i want to handle errors. The problem is that it doesnt catch when the connection to the server is broken. The console simply displays:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PRM_ServerError' of undefined
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._createPageRequestManagerServerError 
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._onFormSubmitCompleted 
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function) 
Sys.Net.WebRequest.completed
```

How can i catch errors when a connection the server is broken? onEndRequest does not even get to fire.

Thanks

Comment: Nope. I sadly did not.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what I found that that AsyncPostBackErrorMessage is null which generate that exception.
I corrected it by changing string before work with it.

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="MyToolkitScriptManager" OnAsyncPostBackError="MyToolkitScriptManager_AsyncPostBackError">

 protected void MyToolkitScriptManager_AsyncPostBackError(object sender, AsyncPostBackErrorEventArgs e)         
 {
 MyToolkitScriptManager.AsyncPostBackErrorMessage = e.Exception.Message;
 }
```